# Kubernetes Helm Chart for Schedulable Jobs - Issues with 'TestVerifyRestartPolicyIsNever' and Potential Other Errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**Problem Description:**

I'm developing a Helm chart to deploy schedulable jobs in Kubernetes.  My chart aims to provide flexibility for developers to customize job definitions. However, I'm encountering the following

**Errors during testing validation:**

```
TestObligatoryCountIsValid
Output (stderr):
helm_cron_job_count_test.go:83: Should define 2 objects of type CronJob, defined 1
WRONG ANSWER
TestVerifyNoDefinitionCountIsValid
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCountOneIsValid
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyBiggerCountIsValid
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyConcurrencyPolicyDefaultValueIsSetCorrectly
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCronJobFailHistoryIsDefined
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCronJobSuccessHistoryIsDefined
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCronJobConcurrencyPolicyIsDefined
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCronJobStartingDeadlineIsDefined
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCronJobNameIsSetCorrectly
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyCronJobScheduleIsSetCorrectly
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER

TestVerifyRestartPolicyIsNever
Output (stderr):
This test was not scored, because some obligatory tests failed.
WRONG ANSWER
```

**Code Snippets (with Detailed Descriptions):**

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob 
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-cronjob  
spec:
 {{ range $index, $job := .Values.jobs }} 
  schedule: {{ $job.schedule }}
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid 
  suspend: false  
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:       
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: {{ $job.name }} 
            image: {{ $job.image }}
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "{{ $job.script }}"]  # As a list     
  {{- end }}
```

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

I've ensured that top-level kind fields (CronJob, Container) are present.
I'm attempting to provide a string value for spec.schedule in my values.yaml.
Environment:

1. Helm v3.0.2
2. Kubernetes v1.17

**Requirement:**

- - Use batch/v1beta1 in the CronJob definition.

- Default values (when the value is not provided in the
  file) should be:
- allowConcurrentRuns:false
- deadlineToStart:200
- failedExecutionLimit:4
- history
- history.success:1
- history.failure:7
- history can be nil, not interface
- The restartPolicy field in the jobTemplate container should be configurable & should always be set to Neve.
- The execution environment is Helm v3.0.2 and Kubernetes 1.17.

Comment: What code produces the diagnostic output you show at the beginning?  Is there a specific YAML-syntax set of Helm values that's required?  If the person using this Helm chart has to provide most of the Job setup as "configuration", would it be more straightforward for them to write out CronJob specs in their chart's `templates` directory?